# Create random points within polygons with certain distance to polygon boundaries using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, distance, samplepoints

I am using PostGIS and have a table containing a polygon geometry and a text column containing different factors.
I need to create 5000 sample points, which are located IN the polygons and are at least a distance of 10m away from the polygon boundary.
Furthermore, the points should be distributed in a way, that they cover all different factors.

What I tried so far:
Loop over the factors and create 150 points for every factor. I thought the third argument in the function would mean the distance to the polygons, but when I look at the created point layer in QGIS, there's no distance of 10m to the boarders. Furthermore, there are created 150 points in every polygon, but I want 150 points for all polygons having the specific factor.

- How can I include the distance to the polygon boundary?
- How can I create 150 points in all polygons with the specific factor instead of 150 poinsts in every polygon with the specific factor?
- Is there another function to achieve this?

```
SELECT ST_GeneratePoints(ST_SetSRID(geom,31287), 150, 10) 
FROM table 
WHERE factor = 'some_factor'
```

Comment: Could you use a negative buffer instead and if it doesn't have enough vertices, generate new ones?

Comment: It sounds like you want to say "and are at least a distance of 6m away from the polygon boundary".

Comment: @TimothyDalton I looked for the function ST_Buffer, but I just found out how to create Buffers around points, but not how to create points within polygons. I'm quiet new to PostGIS, sorry!

Comment: As suggested, the way to generate points at least 10 m inside a polygon is to run `ST_GeneratePoints` on `ST_Buffer(poly, -10)`.

Comment: Are the polygons non-overlapping?

Comment: Your query is missing any attempt to limit the creation to a spatial constraint. Try using the [documented syntax](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeneratePoints.html), then altering the `geom` in the virtual table to be a negative buffer.  The ST_SetSRID isn't likely to help if the table isn't already in 31287.

Comment: The polygons are non-overlapping. I created the points with a negative buffer around them. What I am wondering about now is that they change position when I zoom in and out in QGIS.

Comment: @talocodat if you display a query result in QGIS, the underlying query will be rerun every time the map canvas changes state, i.e. the query results are bounded to the current map extent, and when leaving the current bounds, a rerun is triggered. The function results are random, so the actual point geometries change. You'd need to persist the query result either in the DB (`CREATE TABLE`/`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW`) or export the layer to file within QGIS.

Comment: Can you compute a weighted number of points per polygon based on the fraction of total polygons area?  Then assign each point to a factor, perhaps randomly?